# Get RadioButton Value KnockoutJs

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

I have dynamically created radio buttons in my view and i am trying to pass the checked value to my controller. When my controller is hit the Agentcode string is Empty and i cant figure out how to grab the value so i can send it to my controller.

EDIT my radio buttons are generated in a foreach which i think may be causing the difficulty in reaching the value.

This is what the html rendered by the MVC control looks like

```
<div>
<input name="XXXXX" type="radio" value="{ data_bind = checkedValue: $data,checked: $root.AgentCode }">
 </div> 

  foreach (var code in Model.ActiveAgentCodes)
    {
        <div>
            @Html.RadioButton(code.AgentCode, new { data_bind="checkedValue: $data,checked: $root.AgentCode"})

     @Html.RadioButton(code.AgentCode, new {data_bind="checkedValue: $data,checked: $root.AgentCode"}) }
```

my knockout ViewModel looks like this.

```
 function ViewModel(){
    var self = this;
    self.AgentCode = ko.observable();
    };

    var viewModel = new ViewModel();
    ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

and the post method in my controller looks like this

```
   [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult GetAgentCodeForHomeController(string AgentCode)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Home", "Home");
        }
```

In my view i am posting using like so

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("GetAgentCodeForHomeController", "ChangeAccount"))
{
        @Html.RadioButton(code.AgentCode, new {data_bind="checkedValue: $data,checked: $root.AgentCode"})
   @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.AgentCode, new { data_bind = "text:AgentCode" })
}
<button type="submit">OK</button>
```

Comment: don't know much about the razor syntax for html in mvc, so would you mind sharing the html that is rendered?

Comment: @gkb i have included the rendered html

Comment: can you replace `data_bind` (underscore) with `data-bind` (dash) and then try?

Comment: in an MVC control you have to use data_bind. You get red squiggles when  i tried to use data-bind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to send data back to my controller and the best way that i found was to add properties to my viewmodel.

```
public string AgentCode {get; set;}
```

Then give the radio buttons an Id so that when the controller is hit MVC maps the properties correctly. I decided to not go with knockout and instead post the form back to the controller. It ended up looking like this on my buttons.

```
@Html.RadioButton("AgentCode", code.AgentCode, new {id = code.AgentCode})
```